# How to get Azure B2C Access Token on MVC app using Owin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, cookies, azure-ad-b2c

My latest project has me making a MVC application.  Basic requirements of the application are that is allows a user to sign in with Azure ADD B2C and allows users to manipulate data on an Azure App Service database.  Following this article [here](http://bitoftech.net/2016/08/31/integrate-azure-ad-b2c-asp-net-mvc-web-app/), I've managed to successfully log a user in to B2C.  However, I'm having trouble getting to the second part of my application starting with signing in to app service.  I know that I need to get an access token from B2C to pass on to the app service to verify.  My issue is that I'm only able to get an ID token which app service, as it should, just sends me back a 401.  My OWIN startup class contains the following just like the article:

```
public class Startup
{
    // App config settings
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AadInstance"];
    private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];

    // B2C policy identifiers
    public static string SignUpPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SignUpPolicyId"];
    public static string SignInPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SignInPolicyId"];
    public static string ProfilePolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:UserProfilePolicyId"];

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        // Configure OpenID Connect middleware for each policy
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignUpPolicyId));
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(ProfilePolicyId));
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignInPolicyId));
    }

    // Used for avoiding yellow-screen-of-death
    private Task AuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        notification.HandleResponse();
        if (notification.Exception.Message == "access_denied")
        {
            notification.Response.Redirect("/");
        }
        else
        {
            notification.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
    {
        return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
            // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
            MetadataAddress = String.Format(aadInstance, tenant, policy),
            AuthenticationType = policy,

            // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
            ClientId = clientId,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
            },
            Scope = "openid",
            ResponseType = "id_token",

            // This piece is optional - it is used for displaying the user's name in the navigation bar.
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                SaveSigninToken = true //important to save the token in boostrapcontext
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Things I've tried:

1. Setting the `ResponceType` to `"access_token"`
2. Setting the `Scope` to my custom published scope `"user_impersonation"`
3. I was pretty sure it didn't change anything for the better but I tried setting `NameClaimType` to `"access_token"`
4. A few other things that just threw exceptions left and right.

This is my first MVC web application so I'm still trying to understand how exactly it works; especially the concept of cookies (and even how to store the access token I'm given).  I have however found many helpful instructional videos and articles that have been helping me along.  I just haven't found anything that deals with what I am trying to do.  Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!